# Unique sub-Json of a Json

Tags: json

let me start from a JSon object like

```
[
  {
    "id": 32837732,
    "composer": {
      "id": 536,
      "name": "Francis Poulenc"
    },
    "title": "Of Thee I Sing: Overture (radio version)"
  },
  {
    "id": 32837735,
    "composer": {
      "id": 245,
      "name": "George Gershwin"
    },
    "title": "Concerto in F : I. Allegro"
  },
  {
    "id": 32837739,
    "composer": {
      "id": 245,
      "name": "George Gershwin"
    },
    "title": "Concerto in F : II. Adagio"
  }
]
```

is it possible to get, in a clean, declarative way, a Json like

```
{
'composer': [
                {
                'id': '536',
                'name': 'Francis Poulenc'
                },
                {
                'id': '245',
                'name': 'George Gershwin'
                },
        ]
}
```

That is the unique sub-values for each composer (id and name)?

Comment: This unreadable, put it in code format...

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr= [
  {
    "id": 32837732,
    "composer": {
      "id": 536,
      "name": "Francis Poulenc"
    },
    "title": "Of Thee I Sing: Overture (radio version)"
  },
  {
    "id": 32837735,
    "composer": {
      "id": 245,
      "name": "George Gershwin"
    },
    "title": "Concerto in F : I. Allegro"
  },
  {
    "id": 32837739,
    "composer": {
      "id": 245,
      "name": "George Gershwin"
    },
    "title": "Concerto in F : II. Adagio"
  }
];

var composers=[];
arr.forEach(function(arrElem){
    if(arrElem.composer && !composers.some(function(comp) { return comp.id === arrElem.composer.id && comp.name === arrElem.composer.name }))
          composers.push(arrElem.composer);
});
alert( JSON.stringify( composers ));
```

Comment: Thanks, your code snippet works perfectly here ...
Unfortunately I forgot to say that I'm working in C# ...
Please help again !